# What is so special about positive hydrogen ions that they are used in pH calculation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ph

I just learned about pH. If I understand it correctly, all it really tells is the concentration of positive hydrogen ions (protons) there are in a given liquid.

Why is this pH scale entirely dedicated to positive hydrogen ions? What is so special about protons/hydrogen ions? I would expect the scale to would count all positive ions, even if they are of atoms different from hydrogen. I don't understand why is the proton ion a "superstar", being so special that people made a scale dedicated just to it.

Comment: There's also the $pOH$ scale as well, which works in the same way, but for $OH^{-}$ ions instead... The 'p' denotes $log_{10}$. They're interchangeable; at $25^{°}C$, $pH + pOH = 14$, just like $K_{w} = [H^{+}][OH^{-}]$. They're just logarithmic scales to make it easier to represent small numbers.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/on-the-scale-of-stuff-with-a-ph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we're really talking about with the acidity of a solution is the proportion of *water* which is dissociated into hydroxide $OH^-$ or hydronium ions $H_3O^+$ ([hydronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium) is usually a more accurate representation than a free proton).

Other ions *do* affect the acidity of a solution, but by inducing water to dissociate. Check out the example on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH#pH). Pure water alone has a $pH$, because of spontaneous dissociation of some water molecules into ions. The $pH$ of pure water is 7, because the $pK_a$ of water as a weak acid is 14.

Basically, *water* is the special thing, and its constituent ions happen to be hydroxide and hydrogen / hydronium. Those ions are what we measure with a $pH$ electrode, so the scales are named after them. Water has a concentration around 55 M, vastly predominating in aqueous solutions.

Comment: What is this pKa?

Comment: The pKa is the negative log of the [acid constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant), the equilibrium constant for an Arrhenius acid to give up its proton. The pKa of water is 14, the pKa of vinegar is ~4.8, HCl is -7 (a very strong acid).