# How is the pH scale constructed?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

How is the pH scale constructed , I mean the strength of an acid is determined by its pK<sub>a</sub> value and this one can be determined in different solvents if water doesn't suits it but how do you determine the pK<sub>a</sub> value of a substance in water after you have found the value of its pK<sub>a</sub> in another solvent ? Also I don't think I quite understand why the pH interval in water is running from 0 to 14 (I know that it has to do with the leveling effect but when you take this scale for other solvents the starting value can be different from 0 , if I am not mistaken for liquid NH<sub>3</sub> the starting value is 5 ) can someone explain to me from where does this values come from ?

Comment: First of all the scale in water doesn't go from 0 to 14, it can extend beyond those values (values of -2 to 16 are possible without too much effort in a lab). The scale in liquid ammonia is much larger, covering over 30 units. See [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6997/1499) and [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/5047/1499), as well as several other Chem.SE posts tagged with pH.

Answer (score 2):

The pH is determined experimentally with a glass electrode. A glass electrode is a small glass tube limited by a thin membrane and filled with an aqueous KCl solution with a silver electrode inside. There is also a similar silver electrode out of the tube, in a compartment in contact with the outer solution. When you dip a glass electrode into an aqueous solution, the experiment shows that the tension E read between the two electrodes is proportional to the logarithm of the H+ concentration of the external solution. It is :  E  = Constant + 0.059 pH. The Constant depends of the particular glass membrane.
And the experiment shows that pH is -log[H+] at low acidic concentrations, and is measured as

- 7 in pure water,
- 3 in 0.001 M aqueous solutions
- 2 in 0.01 M aqueous HCl solutions,
- 11 in 0.001 M aqueous NaOH solutions
- 12 in 0.01 M aqueous NaOH solutions.

These values are in agreement with the usual expression : pH = -log[H+], or : pH = 14 - log[OH-]. At higher concentration, the measured pH values are not exactly equal to the logarithm of [H+]. The measured pH is said to be the logarithm of the "activity" of H+.

The pH does not go only from zero to 14. It may be smaller than zero in concentrated solutions of HCl and of H2SO4.

In non-conducting solutions, the glass electrode does not give any stable values. The measured tension is fluctuating without any reason and can be ± 3, 5, 10 or 0, and this changes constantly.

Comment: Maurice's great experimental depiction clearly notes the measurements are created in DILUTE conditions. Otherwise, the 'activity coefficient' is important which is a function of ion charge, ion size and ionic strength. So, in the presence of high ionic concentrations of salts like FeCl3 or CaCl2 with a large ion charge, even dilute HCl can apparently 'act' as a much stronger acid due to the activity coefficient which is applied to [H+]  to determine the pH (see  http://www.csun.edu/~hcchm003/321/321100313.pdf page 4).

Answer (score 0):

The pH+ scale is a logarithmic scale, [based on the number of $\ce{H+}$ ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH) available (with the *caveat* that $\ce{H+}$ is theoretical, it may be $\ce{H3O+}$ or other ionic species). I.E., [in water at ~300 K, ~10<sup>−7</sup> mol dm<sup>−3</sup> of the positive and of the negative ions exist, a pH+ of 7 (the negative exponent).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water)

For a strong acid, virtual *all, 100%,* of the molecules are broken into ions, e.g. $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\ce{H+}$, so the pH+ is 0 [10<sup>−0</sup> = 1].

Note that at different temperatures, [water may be more or less ionized, so a neutral pH+ is not necessarily 7.](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/kw.html) At its boiling point, "neutral" is about 6.14.